# Django image.save() TypeError: get_valid_name() missing positional argument: 'name'

Tags: django, django-models, boto, django-storage

This is what I have tried:

```
r = requests.get(img_url)
temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
temp.write(r.content)
temp.flush()
image = Image()
image.image.save('testimagefilename', File(temp), save=True)
image.save()
```

On the `image.image.save()` line, the error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 90, in save
    name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 332, in generate_filename
    return os.path.join(self.get_directory_name(), self.get_filename(filename))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 322, in get_filename
    return os.path.normpath(self.storage.get_valid_name(os.path.basename(filename)))
TypeError: get_valid_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Is the problem because Django is expecting a local OS path? I'm using S3BotoStorage, the ImageField is using a separate bucket from the rest of the project:

```
image = models.ImageField(storage=S3CustomStorage)

class S3CustomStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket'] = getattr(settings, 'AWS_BUCKET_CUSTOM')
        super(S3CustomStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does it do?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, just runs through the code and the images never gets saved.

Comment: Sorry I lied, I just tried a minimal version of this in shell and it throws: `TypeError: get_valid_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'` when I run the stuff in OP and `image.image.save('testimagefile', File(temp), save=True)`. I didn't find any documentation on `image.save()`

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I've updated the OP with the error trace and information about the storage I'm using

Comment: That line of code creates a new Image object called image. Image refers to the class with the ImageField model.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps see [Trying to understand Django source code and cause of missing argument TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35002973/1240387) and change

```
image = models.ImageField(storage=S3CustomStorage)
```

to

```
image = models.ImageField(storage=S3CustomStorage())
```

I had the identical TypeError ;-) but now it works with the additional () in my case